# How does every block in a blockchain contain all others blocks data if it is immutable?

Tags: hash, blockchain

I'm kind of a starter here in the blockchain ecosystem, and I have some questions, but one really seems to bother me since is kind of contradictory.

When you generate a block, each block contains the Header, that contains the previous hash, and hash representation of the current block data, and some other things.

But if every block references the previous block with the hash that was generated with the current data of that block, and every block is immutable...

***How can every block in a blockchain can have every other block data if the block is immutable, and also if you change the data, the identity hash of the block immediately changes?***

And another one...

***Which is the detailed process that happens when there is a transaction available, and how does it incorporates to the blockchain?***

Maybe this questions seems kind of dumb to some, but I've been searching and no articles or videos have solved my doubts.

Thanks to all, and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

Every block on the blockchain does not have every other block's data. Actually you might have confused it with *Every node (A node is an instance connected to p2p network of blockchain) on blockchain has all the blocks written to the blockchain so far.*
So the statement

> Every block in a blockchain can have every other block data.

is not true. A block only has data that was added to it at the time of creation after that no data can be added or removed from it.

Now towards your 2nd question

> Which is the detailed process that happens when there is a transaction available, and how does it incorporates to the blockchain?

Lets say A transfers B 1 BTC now first of all in order to submit the transaction you have to be connected to blockchain node or a service that is connected to blockchain (bitcoin blockchain in this case) node.
Normally the wallet apps we use to transfer crypto are connected to blockchain node and post our transactions for us.

Once the transaction is given to a node to process initially it is validated and added to what is called mempool which is essentially a place where all the transactions that are yet to be added in blocks live. Mostly nodes have dedicated some space for mempool. Now nodes pick up transaction from mempool (prioritising the one's with higher fee as they get to keep the fee) and add it in a block. This block is called "candidate block".

Nodes start minning candidate block and if they are lucky enough to mine it first the block is broadcasted to the whole network and everyone adds this block to their chain and start minning next block repeating the same process as above.

The Above process is mainly for bitcoin blockchain but other blockchain all of similar processes.

For beginners instead of going through articles and youtube videos i would recommend studying these books to develop a thorough understanding of underlying architecture. There are mainly two type of blockchain (with in crypto eco system) UTXO Based (old ones mainly Bitcoin and its derivaties LTC Zcash DASH etc) and Account Based (New ones Ethereum BNB etc).
For UTXO Based Blockchain.
https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/mastering-bitcoin/9781491902639/ch01.html.
For Account Based Blockchain.
[https://www.amazon.com/Mastering-Ethereum-Building-Smart-Contracts/dp/1491971940](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491971940)

Comment: Oh, all right, now is a lot more clear.

I can't upvote, but thanks!